# How to make an angular modebinding format parser?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I want to make a parse that works like angular modebinding format.
for example:

```
var test = 'this is a test';

{{test}} // output: 'this is a test'
{{go(test)}} // output: go('this is a test')
{{test + ' yes'}} // output: 'this is a test yes'
```

I try code below but is there any liberty that works like this?

```
templatePattern: function (template, item) {
        var row = template;
        for (var key in item) {
            var regx = new RegExp("{{(?:.*\\()?" + key + "(?:\\).*)?}}", "gm");
            var results = regx.exec(row);
            if (results) {
                var found = results[0].replace('{{', '').replace('}}', '');
                found = found.replace(key, item[key]);
                var data = '';
                if (found == item[key])
                    data = found;
                else
                    data = eval(found);

                row = row.replace(regx, data)
            }
        }

        return row;
    },
```

Comment: Why not just use handlebarsJS or something?

Comment: I have a custom format and my own plugin, I want to code it my self..